# AsNoTracking throwing error Method 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery declared on type For DbSet with collection inside

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have an object

```
public partial class FileAttachment
{
  public FileAttachment()
  {
      this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
  }
  public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get; set;}
  ...other propertties
}
```

My context class is having

```
public virtual DbSet<FileAttachment> FileAtttachments {get; set;}
public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags {get; set;} 
public virtual DbSet<Item> Items {get; set;}
   ...
```

I am using it in my controller like

```
MyContext.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(i => i.ItemId == inputId && 
           MyContext.FileAttachments.AsNoTracking.Where(f => f.RecordId == i.ReferenceId && f.RecordType == 'item').Any()).Any();
```

The error I am getting is

**'Method 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Demo.FileAttachment] AsNoTracking()' declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Demo.FileAttachment]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Demo.FileAttachment]''**

I am new to AsNoTracking(). Anyone can tell where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use `AsNoTracking()` once in query. Also with `Any` AsNoTracking has no sense, because you do not load whole entity.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that means if we are using AsNoTracking on the main query, no need to use it in the subquery (in this case inside where clause)?

Comment: Why are you using `AsNoTracking()` all over the place? Or even once? It's not a "go fast" switch. There are no queries and subqueries in LINQ. What you posted here is unusual at the very least and looks like an attempt to convert a slow SQL query to LINQ.

Comment: What is this query trying to do in the first place? That `i` can't appear in both `Where` clauses like this. If `Item` and `FileAttachment` are related they should have properties pointing to each other, eg `Item.Attachments`.

Comment: Use `AsNotacking()` exactly before call `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc. And only when you load whole entities.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos since I don't want the EF work to track/cache, the example in the question is a trimmed down version, where as in my application I have huge data of FileAttachments and other data related to it. I am going wrong here?

Comment: Definitely, and `AsNoTracking()` isn't needed (you're loading BOOLs) but it's unclear what this even does. In the very same expression you have both `Where(i => i.ItemId >= 10)` and `Where(f => f.RecordID == i.ItemId)`. Where does the `i` in the second case come from? Do you have another variable `i` defined earlier?

Comment: As it is, the code is trying to AND an IQueryable and a Boolean. I'm surprised you don't see *more* compilation errors

Comment: Attachement table can have data from other tables like user. The relation is tracked by RecordId and RecordType which didn't include it in the query.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Period. `MyContext.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(i => i.ItemId >= 10)` is an IQueryable. `MyContext.FileAttachments.AsNoTracking.Where(f => f.RecordID == i.ItemId).Any()` is a Boolean. These can't be combined with `&&`.

Comment: the second query is the sub condition of the first query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry I missed it, I have corrected the query. Thanks! Can you see now?

Comment: I see there's no fix. `Where(i => i.ItemId == 10) &&` has no meaning

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Imagine instead of 10 I have an input Id to my controller method. And based on that I want to form the query

Comment: The query would still have multiple compilation problems. The first problem isn't `10`, it's attempting to treat an IQueryable as if it was a boolean. The second is using `i` in two unrelated queries. Either you have a typo, expected that some of the Items would materialize as `i` outside its own query, or you have an outer variable or parameter named `i`, which is simply a bad idea

Comment: @Suresh For it to be a subquery, in the query `Where(i => i.ItemId == 10)` , the closing `)` should be removed.

Comment: If your real requirement is to check for the existense of `item` attachments for a specific ItemID **and**  the classes had proper navigation properties you'd need only `MyContext.FileAttachments.Any(f=>f.RecordType == 'item' && f.Item.Id = ThatItemID)`. No objects are loaded so there's no need for `AsNoTracking()` or `Include()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the patience and suggestions. But I have no chance of relating the FileAttachment with Items directly. 
`MyContext.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(i => i.ItemId == inputId && 
           MyContext.FileAttachments.AsNoTracking.Where(f => f.RecordId == i.ReferenceId && f.RecordType == 'item').Any()).Any();`

Comment: @Suresh Does removing the inner `AsNoTracking` in `MyContext.FileAttachments.AsNoTracking` resolve the issue? In your case, remove `AsNoTracking` altogether because it doesn't make sense in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the actual requirement is to check whether an `Item` with a specific ID has a related FileAttachment of a specific type. There's no need for `AsNoTracking()` for this since the query returns a single boolean, not objects that need tracking.

If the classes had proper navigation properties, the query would be a simple:

```
var found= MyContext.FileAttachments.Any(f=>f.RecordType == 'item' 
                                         && f.Item.Id = ThatItemID);
```

Without them, the LINQ query will have to JOIN the two "unrelated" entities:

```
var query = from item in MyContext.Items
            join person in MyContext.FileAttachmentes
                on file.RecordId equals item.ReferenceId 
            where item.ItemID == ThatId && 
                  file.RecordType == 'item'
            select 1;
var found=query.Any();
```

The lack of navigation properties is a very strong sign that the model is wrong though.

A DbContext isn't a model of the database and doesn't have to mirror it. There's no need to have a *single* DbContext for the entire application either. Even if there are no Foreign Key **Constraints** between `Items` and `FileAttachments` it's possible to add *relations* between the *classes*

Answer (score 0):

`AsNoTracking()` is used to prevent entity tracking by EF. Tracking allows EF to keep track of modifications made and on saving, these changes can be persisted. So, if a query doesn't need tracking (like a simple get query where no data change is persisted), we use `AsNoTracking()`.

In your case, use navigation property if the entities are related instead of calling `Context.Entity`. Also, `AsNoTracking()` needs to specified only once in the query before loading the data.